# Face Detection with camera2 works only in specific orientation (landscape)

Tags: android, face-detection, android-camera2

I'm having trouble to enable Face Detection with `android.hardware.camera2`. It is recognizing faces only in landscape (only on that specific orientation).

App is coded to use only the Front camera and my activity is "locked" in portrait mode. However, it can detect faces only if device is on landscape.

I also tested allowing my activity to be rotated (default android behavior.. destroy/recreate). It did not change anything. Same result. So, I guess that's not the root cause.

**Question**

Do you have any similar issue and could fixed? Do you have any idea about how to fix it?

**Details**

Below is more information about my code...  I configured only a preview session. I'm not interested in capture pictures at this moment... just wanna get a face detected regardless the device orientation (like any app).

I tested it in Samsung S7 and S8.. Result is the same in both devices:

**Code to open camera (I always open the front camera...):**

```
private void openCamera(final int width, final int height) {
    final CameraManager cameraManager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(
            Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
    if (cameraManager != null) {
        ....
        if (facing != null && facing == CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_FRONT) {
            cameraManager.openCamera(cameraId, mCameraStateCallback, null);
        }
        ....
}
```

**When camera is opened, I create my `CaptureRequest`**

```
public void onOpened(@NonNull final CameraDevice cameraDevice) {
    ...
    final SurfaceTexture texture = mTextureView.getSurfaceTexture();

    if (texture != null) {
    ...
        final Surface surface = new Surface(texture);

        mPreviewRequestBuilder = mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
        mPreviewRequestBuilder.addTarget(surface);

        mCameraDevice.createCaptureSession(Collections.singletonList(surface),
                mSessionStateCallback, null);
    }
    ...
}
```

**Then, when session is configured, I set my `CaptureRequest` and start the session:**

```
public void onConfigured(@NonNull final CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
    ...
    // When the session is ready, we start displaying the preview.
    mCameraCaptureSession = cameraCaptureSession;

    // Set Face Detection to simple mode
    mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(
            CaptureRequest.STATISTICS_FACE_DETECT_MODE,
            CameraMetadata.STATISTICS_FACE_DETECT_MODE_SIMPLE);

    // Use face to control AF, exposure and white-balance
    mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_SCENE_MODE,
            CaptureRequest.CONTROL_SCENE_MODE_FACE_PRIORITY);

    // Auto focus should be continuous for camera preview.
    mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE,
            CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);

    mCameraCaptureSession.setRepeatingRequest(mPreviewRequestBuilder.build(),
                        mSessionCaptureCallback, mBackgroundHandler);
    ...
}
```

**Here I try to read check the number of faces detected**

```
public void onCaptureCompleted(@NonNull final CameraCaptureSession session,
        @NonNull final CaptureRequest request, @NonNull final TotalCaptureResult result) {

    final Integer mode = result.get(CaptureResult.STATISTICS_FACE_DETECT_MODE);
    final Face[] faces = result.get(CaptureResult.STATISTICS_FACES);

    if(faces != null && mode != null) {
        // IF DEVICE IS IN PORTRAIT, faces is not null but always have lenght == 0
        // If DEVICE IS IN LANDSCAPE, faces is not null but return lenght == 1
    }
}
```